# Search Filename based on extension ONLY discarding types

Tags: java, search, filenames

I need to search for files with certain extensions:

examples:

```
hello.txt
hello1.txt
```

But need to discard search if the filenames has similar types:

```
hello.en.txt
hello1.es.txt
hello_es.txt etc
```

Same folder / sub folders might contain both file types.

How do you parse this kind of recursive files?

Thanks,
Kino

Comment: Did you read [this](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-find-files-with-certain-extension-only/) !!!

Comment: What do you mean by But need to discard search if the filenames has similar types:?

Comment: i am trying to search files only with Name.Extension and not Name.Something.Extension. Latter should not be considered.